# Proof of Direct Sum of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Given a space $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ I have proved that the plane $M= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x+y+z=0\}$ and the line $N:\{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x=-\frac{3}{4}y=3z\}$ are both subspaces of $V$.

Now I have trouble proving if $V$ is the direct sum of these two subspaces or not. In order to do that I found the span of $M$ and $N$ to be :
\begin{equation}
M=\left( (1,0,-1)^T, (0,1,-1)^T\right)=(\mu_1^T, \mu_2^T), \quad N=((1,-4/3,1/3)^T)=(\nu_1^T)
\end{equation} 
I showed that the vectors that span $M$ are linearly independent and then I tried to show that there are $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that every $w \in M \cap N$ can be written as a linear combination of $\mu_1,\mu_2, \nu_1$, meaning $w=a\mu_1+b\mu_2=c\nu_1$ where $w\neq 0$ *(since $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ linearly independent)* and at least one of $a,b$ to be non-zero. I ended up with the relation:
\begin{equation}
(a,b,c)=c(1,-4/3,1)
\end{equation}
and for $c=1$ we get $(a,b,c)=(1,-4/3,1)$ which satisfies the above. Now, I have proved that $V$ cannot be written as the direct sum of $M$ and $N$.

Am I correct?

Thank you guys!

Comment: I you have found a non-trivial linear relation between $\mu_1,\mu_1,\nu$, then indeed the sum $M+N$ cannot be direct (and nothing can be written as "that direct sum"). What is strange is requiring $w\in M\cap N$, since if the sum were direct, that intersection would only contain the zero vector.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Well tbh, I am kind lost in traslation. I mean, I now study all this stuff in detail and perhaps I made a wrong assumption at some point of the proof. You are more than welcome in correcting me!

Comment: Since a a line through the origin either lies completely within a plane that contains the origin or intersects it only at the origin, it might be simpler to check whether or not $N\subset M$, i.e., whether or not $\nu_1^T=a\mu_1^T+b\mu_2^T$ for some $a$ and $b$ not both zero. That can be done quickly by computing a certain dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are essentially showing is that $M\cap N$ is non-trivial (I think wording such as "every $w\in M\cap N$ can be written as a linear combination of..." is a bit confusing).

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ any non-trivial vector subspaces are either a line or plane through origin. And you know very well that they can either intersect at origin, or the line lies on the plane. In the former case, the two subspaces form a direct sum, in latter case they don't.

So when asked whether these two subspaces form a direct sum or not, the first thing you check is if the line lies on the plane: this happens precisely when any solutions to the equations of the line is a solution to the equation of plane.

Check that in your example if $x=-3/4 y=3z$ then $x+y+z=0$. This is sufficient to show that

$$
N\subset M
$$

and they can't possibly form a direct sum.

If they intersect at origin only, then you should be able to solve the simultaneous equation uniquely with solution $x=y=z=0$. In that case you actually have shown that $M\cap N=\{0\}$ and you just need to show that $M+N=V$ (and this will always be the case in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

In general abstact vector spaces you have to check first whether or not $M\cap N=\{0\}$ and then whether or not $M+N=V$.

Comment: Thank you. The alternative you suggest is also interesting and a lot faster. But I need some work out with linear algebra to be able to see that, like you did.

Comment: @Mitscaype You're welcome :). Glad it helped you in some way

Answer (score 1):

You found a vector in the intersection $M\cap N$ tat is nonzero. Direct sum requires that $M\cap N = \{0\}$ and hence you are right $V$ is not a direct sum.